# windows Login script help

Tags: windows-xp, mapping, login-script

I am looking for a script that will place a subdirectory in each users home directory.

In the login script we map a drive, so maybe we can just add a line to that to create new folder ‘md’ but once it’s created we need to be sure it ‘fails’ on the subsequent logins with no input requirement from user

I am thinking that a IF exists or not exists might work if any one can help please enclude examples thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following line in a login script should work:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\the_dir" md "%USERPROFILE%\the_dir"
```